# Workaround for digits in beginning of identifier

Tags: naming-standards

Suppose I have a `std::span`-like type, that represents a matrix or an image, or a class modelling a 3d mesh. I would like to say

```cpp
template<class T>
class 2d_span;

class 3d_mesh;
```

But that would obviously not compile. What to do instead:

1. Use exotic unicode symbols. They are sometimes hard to read (depending on font), and even harder to type.
2. Use roman numerals as prefix like `IId_span`, and `IIId_mesh`. It is easy to explain and to type, but would require an explanation in the style guide.
3. Use suffix instead of prefix `span_2d`, and `mesh_3d. This may also seem strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just flip the word order, e.g. `Span3D`. That's how most libraries I'm aware of do it, it is fairly readable, and it can be typed with ASCII-only characters.

You will quickly get used to this word order, after all you're writing C++, not English. Similarly, method call syntax doesn't follow English grammar and it's fine. For example, "resize the window to 42px" is usually expressed as `window.resize(42)`.

If the digit absolutely must come first, it may be possible to "escape" it by using a leading underscore, e.g. `_42`. However, this is easily mistaken for a private or compiler-internal identifier. In nearly all cases, choosing a name that starts with a word will be more appropriate.

Comment: every game developer is surely familiar with their favourite library's vec2/vec2f/Vector2f type.